# Python matching script does not return True or False

Tags: python, string, comparison, matching

I wrote some code to match my TV names. I took only one row from my df, that should be a match, but is not match, to check what's wrong with my code:

```
Data = {'name':  ['LG 43UJ634V'],
        'comp_name': ['LG 43UJ634V'],
        'manufacturer': ['LG'],
        'comp_manufacturer': [''],
        'category': ['TVs']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['name','comp_name', 'manufacturer', 'comp_manufacturer'])
```

My code that does the match for these items is here:

```
    our_name =df['name'].iloc[0].lower()
    comp_name = df['comp_name'].iloc[0].lower()
    brand = df['manufacturer'].iloc[0].lower()
    comp_brand = df['comp_manufacturer'].iloc[0].lower()

    print('Our name:', our_name)
    print('Comp name:', comp_name)
    print('Brand:', brand)
    print('Comp_brand:', comp_brand)

    our_name = our_name.replace(brand, '').strip()
    our_name = our_name.replace(comp_brand, '').strip()
    print('Our name after brand removal:', our_name)

    splitOurName = our_name.split(' ')
    print('Our name split:', splitOurName)

    counter= 0
    for j in splitOurName:
        if j in comp_name:
            counter = counter + 1
    print('counter:', counter)
    if counter == len(splitOurName):
        if ((len(our_name.split(' ')) == 1 and our_name.isalpha()) or
            (len(comp_name.split(' ')) == 1 and comp_name.isalpha()) or
            len(our_name) <= 4):
            print('No match')
        else:
            print('Perfect match')
```

The idea is that I only need to check that unique combination of letters and numbers in our name, nothing else is needed(no symbols, no additional words, no brand, etc). If that combination is in competitors name, then I can say it's a match. I check this using some counter that checks if all remaining strings from our name are found in competitors name(in this case it's only one string, but my original dataframe has many names that have more than one string after all corrections). If so then it's a match. So current code prints out "Perfect match". But if I replace last two print's with "return True" and "return False" accordingly, I get 'NaN' when I call it as a function for my test dataframe(exact same one). What is the problem that I do not see here?

**UPDATE:**

I updated the dataframe, and this is how I call the function that applies to the test dataframe:

```
df.loc[df.category.isin(['TVs']), 'match'] = df.loc[df.category.isin(['TVs'])].apply(tv_match, axis=1)
```

Expected result:
df['match'] == True

Result I get:
df['match'] == NaN

Comment: I think you are making some error whle calling the function.

Comment: You should show us how you have called the function including the input arguments (if there are any), the expected and the observed result.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked well for me. Are you sure you are calling it correctly?

```
import pandas as pd

Data = {'name':  ['LG 43UJ634V'],
        'comp_name': ['LG 43UJ634V'],
        'manufacturer': ['LG'],
        'comp_manufacturer': ['']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['name','comp_name', 'manufacturer', 'comp_manufacturer'])

def sample():
    our_name =df['name'].iloc[0].lower()
    comp_name = df['comp_name'].iloc[0].lower()
    brand = df['manufacturer'].iloc[0].lower()
    comp_brand = df['comp_manufacturer'].iloc[0].lower()

    print('Our name:', our_name)
    print('Comp name:', comp_name)
    print('Brand:', brand)
    print('Comp_brand:', comp_brand)

    our_name = our_name.replace(brand, '').strip()
    our_name = our_name.replace(comp_brand, '').strip()
    print('Our name after brand removal:', our_name)

    splitOurName = our_name.split(' ')
    print('Our name split:', splitOurName)

    counter= 0
    for j in splitOurName:
        if j in comp_name:
            counter = counter + 1
    print('counter:', counter)
    if counter == len(splitOurName):
        if ((len(our_name.split(' ')) == 1 and our_name.isalpha()) or
            (len(comp_name.split(' ')) == 1 and comp_name.isalpha()) or
            len(our_name) <= 4):
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(sample())
```